# Pebble - change text layer text after delay

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm creating a new Pebble watchface. What I need to do is display some text in a text layer, then after a short delay change it to different text. What's the best way to achive this?

I have tried following:

```
text_layer_set_text(s_status_layer, "updated");
psleep(1000);
text_layer_set_text(s_status_layer, "ok");
```

The problem with above is that "updated" is never displayed. Pebble simply keeps displaying whatever text was on "s_status_layer" originally and after 1 second changes it to "ok".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use an **AppTimer** (https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/Foundation/Timer/) :

```
 AppTimer *updateTimer = app_timer_register(1000, (AppTimerCallback) update_timer_callback, NULL);

    void update_timer_callback(void *data) {

       text_layer_set_text(s_status_layer, "ok");

      }
```